# TableView problem with Tab Bar?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I created a tableView which worked fine in a single view app but as soon as I changed the view controller for a Tab Bar Controller and tapped the tab for the view with the table view in I suddenly get this! What has gone wrong?

```
[Session started at 2010-03-28 15:30:15 +0100.]
2010-03-28 15:30:17.763 LogbookTable[13473:207] *** -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b14d10
2010-03-28 15:30:17.765 LogbookTable[13473:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b14d10'
2010-03-28 15:30:17.766 LogbookTable[13473:207] Stack: (
    29303899,
    2465178889,
    29685819,
    29255286,
    29107906,
    4372518,
    4379894,
    4378891,
    3095430,
    3035941,
    3077376,
    3065931,
    55820976,
    55820399,
    55818438,
    55817530,
    2739877,
    2763572,
    2745983,
    2773089,
    37399897,
    29088640,
    29084744,
    2739733,
    2777007,
    10496,
    10350
)
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's trying to send a `numberOfRowsInSection`  message to an UIViewController instead of an UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an UIViewController somewhere, that should be an UITableViewController. Check your view hierarchy in Interface Builder.

Comment: I found my problem, I had just set up the wrong type of view controller for my tab bar in interface builder, silly me!